# Где хранятся координаты и размеры окон, которые находятся в таскбаре?

Tags: windows

Хотелось бы узнать, где на экране монитора появятся окна которые, на текущий момент, находятся в таскбаре.
Возможно данная информация хранится в реестре в текстовом виде или в каком-нибудь текстовом файле.
Хотелось бы узнать их адреса.

Comment: Это хранится в менеджере окон.

Answer (score 0):

В структуре `WINDOWPLACEMENT`, которая хранится в свойстве `HWND` дескриптора окна

- length: длина структуры
- flags: флаги
- showCmd: режим отображения окна (свернуто, развернуто или свёрнуто в системный трей)
- ptMinPosition: координаты точки минимизации окна
- ptMaxPosition: координаты точки максимизации окна
- rcNormalPosition: координаты и размеры окна в нормальном состоянии